# 'AttributeError : 'numpy.float32' object has no attribute 'ctypes''

Tags: c#, numpy, opencv

I'm trying to compute the dimensions of an image from the points that are ordered from Top-Left, Top-Right, etc.. so I can later perform a 4 point perspective transform & warp. (Using opencvSharp & numpy.net)

I want to get the max-width and max-height as an integer from the
NDarray but at this point it throws
" Python.Runtime.PythonException: 'AttributeError : 'numpy.float32' object has no attribute 'ctypes''

Not quite sure how to go about this as a Novice and this my first time working with this OpencvSharp and numpy.NET.

```
NDarray rect = OrderPoints(pts);
            // 4 Points order from top-left top- right etc..
            NDarray tL = rect[0],
                tR = rect[1],
                bR = rect[2],
                bL = rect[3];
      

                           // width of new image
            NDarray w1 = ((bR[0] - bL[0]) * (bR[0] - bL[0])) + ((bR[1] - bL[1]) * (bR[1] - bL[1])); // quietly throws exception here 
            NDarray w2 = ((tR[0] - tL[0]) * (tR[0] - tL[0])) + ((tR[1] - tL[1]) * (tR[1] - tL[1]));

             w1 = np.sqrt(w1);
             w2 = np.sqrt(w2);

            // get max width as an interger

             int[] width1 = w1.GetData<int>(); // same error blows up here
            int[] width2 = w2.GetData<int>();

            int maxWidth = Math.Max(width1[0], width2[0]);
          


            NDarray h1 = ((tR[0] - bR[0]) * (tR[0] - bR[0])) + ((tR[1] - bR[1]) * (tR[1] - bR[1]));
            NDarray h2 = (tL[0] - bL[0]) * (tL[0] - bL[0]) + (tL[1] - bL[1]) * (tL[1] - bL[1]);

           h1 = np.sqrt(h1);
            h2 = np.sqrt(h2);

            int[] height = h1.GetData<int>();
            int[] height2 = h2.GetData<int>();


            int maxHeight = Math.Max(height[0], height2[0]);

            // make a top - down view
            var dst = np.array(
                  new[,] {
                     { 0,0},
                     {maxWidth - 1, 0 },
                     {maxWidth - 1, maxHeight - 1 },
                     {0, maxHeight - 1 }
                      });
            
              var rectPts = rect.GetData<Point2f>();
               var dstarray = dst.GetData<Point2f>();


             Mat matr = Cv2.GetPerspectiveTransform(rectPts, dstarray);
            Mat output = new Mat();
            Cv2.WarpPerspective(image, output, matr, new Size(maxWidth, maxHeight)); 

            return output;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to come up with a solution, by using the `repr` Property to return a string of the data then parse it to a float then cast to an Int.

```
int width1 = (int)float.Parse(w1.repr);
int width2 = (int)float.Parse(w2.repr);
```